# redirect primary domain and support.example.com to https except all other subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am creating wildcard subdomain for usernames and also i created SubDomain for support centre that support.example.com

I have already installed SSL certificate on Primary Domain (example.com) and (support.example.com) and used following .htaccess for automatically redirection to https url.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But all other wildcard subdomains for usernames created dynamically but they don't have SSL certificate.

I want example.com and support.example.com to redirected to https and all other sub domains on http only.

Can anyone tell me what changes i make in my htaccess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the first `RewriteRule` doing?

However, I suggest you may put an additional `RewriteCond` into your second `RewriteRule` to only redirect to https when on example.com and support.example.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(support\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```